# How to draw ON/OFF chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, polymer

I am trying to use the google-chart polymer element (http://googlewebcomponents.github.io/google-chart/components/google-chart/) to draw a Ligth ON/OFF chart.

This is what I get using a "area" chart.

[image: my chart]

However I want a graph where I can read the "state" of the light, hence a better representation would be use a step chart. This is my code that uses the "stepped-area" chart.

```
this.$.chart.type = "stepped-area";
this.$.chart.cols = [{label:"Date", type:"date"}, {label:"On/Off", type:"number"}];
this.$.chart.rows = chartData;
this.$.chart.options = { strictFirstColumnType: "false", backgroundColor: "transparent" };
this.$.chart.drawChart();
```

However when I am trying to use a *date* type as my first column I get a "Stepped area series with value domain axis is not supported.".

Is there another way to do that? 
Maybe setting some other option (*strictFirstColumnType: "false"* is not working)?

Answer (score 2):

Eventually my workaround was using string dates.

Here it follows the code:

```
this.graphs[tuple.uuid].cols =  [{label:"Date", type:"string"}, {label: tuple.behavior, type:"number"}];
this.graphs[tuple.uuid].rows =  [];
this.graphs[tuple.uuid].options =  {
   backgroundColor: "transparent",
   hAxis: { 
      slantedText: true
   },
   vAxis: { 
      minValue:0,
      maxValue:1,
      gridlines:{count:2},
      ticks: [{v:1.00, f:'ON'}, {v:0.00, f:'OFF'}] 
   }
};
this.graphs[tuple.uuid].type = "stepped-area";
```

This is my final result:

[image]

The date label is still not easy to read but the final result is not bad at all.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a `timeline`-chart, like in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/dx0Lw52b/

[image]